# Retrieving data from column depending on another column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got one table Employee with columns

```
| EmpID | Name | Department | Supervisor |
```

- The ID is the primary key, and is an integer.
- The Name is a string
- The supervisor is an integer referring to an Employee.

I want to list all Employees next to the name of their supervisor.

```
 SELECT empid, name, supervisor
 FROM Employee;
```

gives me:

```
+-------+--------+------------+
| empid | name   | supervisor |
+-------+--------+------------+
|     1 | John   |       NULL |
|     2 | Roger  |       NULL |
|     3 | Pete   |       NULL |
|     4 | Rafael |       NULL |
|     5 | Rafael |          1 |
|     6 | Obama  |          1 |
|     7 | Karl   |          1 |
|     8 | Carl   |          1 |
|     9 | Moni   |          2 |
|    10 | Dave   |          9 |
|    11 | David  |          9 |
|    12 | Carl   |          9 |
|    13 | Linda  |       NULL |
|    14 | Maria  |       NULL |
|    15 | Monk   |          3 |
|    16 | Peter  |       NULL |
|    17 | Pete   |          4 |
|    18 | Marina |          4 |
|    19 | John   |          4 |
|    20 | Alvaro |          4 |
+-------+--------+------------+
```

my desire is to get this , but instead of a number ID in the supervisor column, I want the actual name that number ID.

How can I do this? I guess I need a fancy nested queries but I cant figure out how to do this from mysql's documentation

Comment: If you found that an answer is correct and useful, give it an upvote and mark the best one as the accepted answer for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a `JOIN`

A `JOIN` allows you to generate the cartesian product of two data sets, which can then be filtered as needed. Often, you join tables on the foreign keys or other significant indexes. In your case you want to join this table with itself on the empID-supervisor relationship. Here's how:

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, s.name 
FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN Supervisor s ON e.supervisor = s.id
```

Join syntax is very powerful and needs some time to be mastered properly. To understand it better and to get a solid starting point, i advise you to read the **[OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)**

Answer (score 0):

```
select Employee.id, Employee.name, Supervisor.name from Employee left join Supervisor on Employee.supervisor = Supervisor.id
```

Comment: Hello! this website isn't about the fastest answer, but it's rather about learning and improving. You should explain a bit why your query works and what it's the reasoning behind it

Comment: Ok .. it's my first answer on stackoverlow.

Comment: Do not worry, the answer is correct. Just expand it a little bit, to help others to understand WHY it's correct.